# Module installed on Conda, but gives error on importing in Spyder (Python IDE)

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I recently installed [pybedtools](https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/main.html#quick-install-via-conda) in my Conda environment, using the command they mentioned -

`conda install -c bioconda pybedtools`

But then when I activated spyder in this environment, and tried to run `import pybedtools` it gave me the error-

`Modulenotfounderror: no module named 'pybedtools'`

I went back and tried to install using the module using `pip` too (`pip install pybedtools`) but it said that I already had it -

`Requirement already satisfied: pybedtools in /anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: six in ./anaconda3/envs/env1/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from pybedtools)`

So, I am unable to understand how it is that the module is installed yet Spyder does not allow me to import it. I have never faced this issue with Anaconda before. Any help would be great!

Comment: This worked-> activate the environment `root`, and install the module there. Then go back to your original environment and the error is gone. Strange work-around though!

Comment: You should post this as an answer.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I was able to solve the issue -

1. activate the `root` environment. This can be done by `activate root` in Windows and `source activate root` in Ubuntu/Mac
2. install the said package here. This can be done using the same command that you used to install the package in your previous environment
3. Go back to your original environment. The problem will now be resolved.

I would love to know, though, why this method works!