# Python - No module found

Tags: python, macos

I'm new to Python and because I couldn't find a solution for my problem after some researches in google, I'm creating a new question, where I'm sure someone for 100% asked for it already. I have installed miniconda with numpy and pandas, which I want to use. It's located at `~/miniconda`. I've created new python file in `~/Desktop`, where I have imported those two libraries:
`import numpy as np`
`import pandas as pd`
When I run my code, I got an error message:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`

How can I make miniconda libraries visible in console for the `python` command?

Comment: Yes, I have also installed Anaconda Navigator, from where I can run Jupyter Notebook and there all works ok

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47519807/module-installed-on-conda-but-gives-error-on-importing-in-spyder-python-ide ?

Answer (score 1):

conda has its own version of the Python interpreter. It is located in the Miniconda directory (It's called "Python.exe"). If you are using an IDE you need to switch the interpreter to use this version of Python rather than the default one you may have installed on the internet from the Python website itself.

Answer (score 0):

In Anaconda Navigator, I have already installed those libraries. What I have done was to delete them and install once again. Now it works for me from both: console and Jupyter Notebook.